# A problem that involves matrix and Lorentz Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, mp.mathematical-physics, matrix-theory

To be clear I address the question in two parts as below. All matrixes involved are real four-dimensional matrixes.

$1.$Let $G$ be the matrix $diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$. $A$ is a matrix satisfying $A G A^T=A^T G A=G$. Since $A A^T>0$, there exists $B=B^T$ and $B^2=A A^T$. Do we always have $B^TGB=G$?

$2.$Directly we get $|detA|=1$ and by dividing $A$ into $4$ blocks we get $|a_{11}|\geq 1$ ($a_{11}$ is the number located in the first row and first column of $A$). Consider the case $detA=1$ and $a_{11}\geq1$. For exactly the same reason there exists $B=B^T$ and $B^2=A A^T$. Let $C=B^{-1} A$, can we find such $B$ that $C$ can be written as $diag(1,R)$ where $R R^T=I=diag(1,1,1,1)$?

Here are some simple results of mine for Q1:

$a.$$(B^TGB)^2=B^TGBB^TGB=B^TGAA^TGB=B^T(GAG)(GA^TG)B=B^TA^{-T}A^{-1}B=B^T(AA^T)^{-1}B=I=diag(1,1,1,1)$

$b.$$B^T(B^TGB)B=BBGBB=AA^TGAA^T=AGA^T=G$

As I said in the title, the problem came from a friend of mine majoring in theoretical physics, who was trying to write a Lorentz Transformation Matrix as the product of the two kinds of matrixes as $B$ and $C$ in Q2.

Comment: How did you encounter this problem?  Have you looked at http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/882/how-to-write-a-good-mathoverflow-question?cb=1 ?

Comment: @S.Carnahan It came from a friend of mine majoring in theoretical physics.

Comment: @S.Carnahan I am new to mathoverflow, and I am sorry if there is anything wrong in my question.

Comment: @S.Carnahan My friend just said that the problem has to do with Lorentz Transformation. She was trying to write a Lorentz Transformation Matrix as the product of the two kinds of matrixes as $B$ and $C$ which appear in Q2.

Comment: I believe that this question’s aim is to decompose a Lorentz transformation into a boost and a rotation.  But this is not the way to go about it.  In any case, it’s hardly research mathematics, so I’m voting to close.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill Thanks for the information, I will check it with my friend.

Comment: BTW, Michael Renardy's example _can_ in fact be extended to four dimensions. But the reason that it is not a counterexample to the "physics statement" is that the theorem states every restricted Lorentz transformation has this decomposition. In particular, for part (1) you need also $\det A > 0$ and $a_{11} > 0$. The proof can be found in, for example, [these notes of Arthur Jaffe](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1288789.files/Rotations-Lorentz-Transformations.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a two-dimensional counterexample:
Let $$A=\pmatrix{\sqrt{2}&-1\cr 1&-\sqrt{2}}$$
and $$G=\pmatrix{1&0\cr 0&-1}.$$
You can check that $AGA^T=A^TGA=G$. Now let
$$B=\pmatrix{1&\sqrt{2}\cr \sqrt{2}&1}.$$
Then $B^2=AA^T$, but $BGB\neq G$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe the matrixes mentioned in the question are all four-dimensional ones. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: According to my friend, the answer to the question is guaranteed by physics.

Comment: You can fill up two-dimensional matrices with zeros and make them four-dimensional.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: to nit-pick, filling up with zeros will not make an element of $O(1,1)$ an element of $O(1,3)$.